# What is the advantage of relationships between tables in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, relation

I made three tables.
**Table1=users**.And the column names are **userid (auto_increment)** and **username**.
**Table2=hobbies**. column names are **hobbyid (auto_increment)** and **hobbyname**.
**Table3=users_hobbies**. column names are **FK_userid** and **FK_hobbyid**.

Now whenever I **register new user and his/her hobbies** from a html form, I **select the

corresponding userid and hoobyid** that is generated from table 1 and table 2
and **insert them to table 3 using query**

So what is the use of relationship, if I create it between table 1 and 3 and table 2 and 3?
Will the corresponding userid and hobbyid **automatically** go to table 3 **without using query**?

Comment: No, a foreign key relationship from table 3 verifies that the user record in table 1 and the hobby record in table 2 exist before allowing an entry to be created in table 3... otherwise you end up with lots of orphaned records clogging up your table 2, so it's an automatic validation; and if you do a cascade delete on table 1, it will automatically delete any related table 3 records for you

Comment: thanks! i was really having problems of orphaned records when updating the user details...will now use relationship..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the userid and hobbyid won't go automatically anywhere.

The major point of relationships or rather constraints is to enforce data integrity. That means you shouldn't be able to add an entry containing id 2, 2 into the users_hobbies table without a user with id 2 and a hobby with id 2.

In order to keep this integrity you can also specify cascadings. (Depending on the Database system, I hardly work with mysql, so I am not sure about that).

That means, you can specify that all users_hobbies for user with id 1 are deleted if the user himself is deleted.